# Overlapping text labels in ordination plot - base R

Tags: r, text, pca, overlap, label

There have been a few questions that have skirted around this topic but I haven't found any of those solutions to work for me. My issue is that I'm unable to get my text labels in an ordination plot (db-RDA) to not overlap. I'm plotting in base graphics. I have tried using a combination of `pos=`, and `offset=`, and while this allows for some changing of positions, they do not fully solve the issue.

My code is:

```
plot(dbrdacom,type='none',display=c('bp','sites'))
points(dbrdacom, display = "sites", choices = c(1, 2), scaling = 2, 
head.arrow = 0.05, lty=1, pch=16, col=envar$Colour)
text(dbrdacom, display = "cn", choices = c(1, 2), scaling = 2, 
head.arrow = 0.05, lty=1, cex=0.7)
```

If I am at least able to get the arrows without the text, this will allow me to format the graph outside R (blasphemy, I know, but those deadlines are whizzing past!). Adding an example of the graphic I have right now. [db-RDA plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz8Dh.png)

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you could include some of your data to make your question reproducible I could help you. Paste the output of `dput(dbrdacom)` in your question.